# Media Session Notification Not Show in LockScreen in Samsung Android 13

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediasession, samsung

I make an android music apps in kotlin that use media session notification, everything works well in another phone, but in Samsung Android 13 it not show in lockscreen.

In emulator it works,in xiami works also, and in samsung android 10 works also

here the code :

```
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    mm = MusicManager.getInstance(this)
    mm?.setMediaPlayerListener(this)
    mediaSession = MediaSessionCompat(this, "PlayerService")
    mediaSession.isActive = true
    mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS or MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS)

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
        receiver,
        IntentFilter("notification-action")
    )


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            "channel_id",
            "Channel Name",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        )
        
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
        notificationManager?.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}

private fun initializeNotification() {
    imageLoader.loadImageFromUrl(MusicManager.MusicDataProvider.getMusicData()?.image?.l ?: "")

}


private fun updateNotification() {
    updateMetadata()

    val playPauseIcon =
        if (isPlaying) R.drawable.ic_resume_music_white else R.drawable.ic_play_music_white
    val notificationFlags = if (isPlaying) {
        NotificationCompat.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT
    } else {
        0 // Clear any ongoing event flag when paused
    }

    val musicImageBitmap = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.img_lifestyle_music) as BitmapDrawable

    // Build the notification
    val builder =
        NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel_id")
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setColorized(false)
            .setContentIntent(
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this, 0, pendingIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                )
            )
            .setContentTitle(MusicManager.MusicDataProvider.getMusicData()?.songName)
            .setContentText(MusicManager.MusicDataProvider.getMusicData()?.artistName)
            .setLargeIcon(image ?: musicImageBitmap.bitmap)
            .setStyle(
                androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                    .setMediaSession(mediaSession.sessionToken)
                    .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2)
            )
            .addAction(
                R.drawable.ic_previous_music_white,
                "Previous",
                getPendingIntentForAction("previous")

            )
            .addAction(
                playPauseIcon,
                "Play",
                getPendingIntentForAction("playPause")
            )
            .addAction(
                R.drawable.ic_next_music_white,
                "Next",
                getPendingIntentForAction("next")
            )
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setOngoing(isPlaying)
            .build()
            .apply {
                flags = flags or notificationFlags
            }


    // Notify with the updated notification
    if (
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
        )
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        return
    }
    startForeground(100, builder)

}
```

In emulator it works,in xiami works also, and in samsung android 10 works also

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please recheck the code